# Postgresql database server keeps shutting down randomly

Tags: django, linux, database, postgresql

During last two days, it's been five or six times which my **postgres** database server was shut down unexpectedly, often when server traffic was at the lowest level.
So i checked postgresql log:

```
2021-09-18 10:17:36.099 GMT [22856] LOG:  received smart shutdown request
2021-09-18 10:17:36.111 GMT [22856] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 22863) exited with exit code 1
grep: Trailing backslash
kill: (28): Operation not permitted
2021-09-18 10:17:39.601 GMT [55614] XXX@XXX FATAL:  the database system is shutting down
2021-09-18 10:17:39.603 GMT [55622] XXX@XXX FATAL:  the database system is shutting down
2021-09-18 10:17:39.686 GMT [55635] XXX@XXX FATAL:  the database system is shutting down
2021-09-18 10:17:39.688 GMT [55636] XXX@XXX FATAL:  the database system is shutting down
2021-09-18 10:17:39.718 GMT [55642] XXX@XXX FATAL:  the database system is shutting down
2021-09-18 10:17:39.720 GMT [55643] XXX@XXX FATAL:  the database system is shutting down
kill: (55736): No such process
kill: (55741): No such process
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
Failed to stop c3pool_miner.service: Interactive authentication required.
See system logs and 'systemctl status c3pool_miner.service' for details.
pkill: killing pid 654 failed: Operation not permitted
pkill: killing pid 717 failed: Operation not permitted
pkill: killing pid 717 failed: Operation not permitted
log_rot: no process found
chattr: No such file or directory while trying to stat /etc/ld.so.preload
rm: cannot remove '/opt/atlassian/confluence/bin/1.sh': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove '/opt/atlassian/confluence/bin/1.sh.1': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove '/opt/atlassian/confluence/bin/1.sh.2': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove '/opt/atlassian/confluence/bin/1.sh.3': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove '/opt/atlassian/confluence/bin/3.sh': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove '/opt/atlassian/confluence/bin/3.sh.1': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove '/opt/atlassian/confluence/bin/3.sh.2': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove '/opt/atlassian/confluence/bin/3.sh.3': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove '/var/tmp/lib': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove '/var/tmp/.lib': No such file or directory
chattr: No such file or directory while trying to stat /tmp/lok
chmod: cannot access '/tmp/lok': No such file or directory
bash: line 525: docker: command not found
bash: line 526: docker: command not found
bash: line 527: docker: command not found
bash: line 528: docker: command not found
bash: line 529: docker: command not found
bash: line 530: docker: command not found
bash: line 531: docker: command not found
bash: line 532: docker: command not found
bash: line 533: docker: command not found
bash: line 534: docker: command not found
bash: line 547: setenforce: command not found
bash: line 548: /etc/selinux/config: Permission denied
Failed to stop apparmor.service: Interactive authentication required.
See system logs and 'systemctl status apparmor.service' for details.
Synchronizing state of apparmor.service with SysV service script with /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install.
Executing: /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install disable apparmor
Failed to reload daemon: Interactive authentication required.
update-rc.d: error: Permission denied
Failed to stop aliyun.service.service: Interactive authentication required.
See system logs and 'systemctl status aliyun.service.service' for details.
Failed to disable unit: Interactive authentication required.
/tmp/kinsing is 648effa354b3cbaad87b45f48d59c616
2021-09-18 10:17:49.860 GMT [54832] admin@postgres FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command
2021-09-18 10:17:49.860 GMT [54832] admin@postgres CONTEXT:  COPY uegplqsl, line 1: "/tmp/kinsing exists"
2021-09-18 10:17:49.860 GMT [54832] admin@postgres STATEMENT:  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS XXX;CREATE TABLE XXX(cmd_output text);COPY XXXFROM PROGRAM 'echo ... |base64 -d|bash';SELECT * FROM XXX;DROP TABLE IF EXISTS XXX;
2021-09-18 10:17:49.877 GMT [22858] LOG:  shutting down
2021-09-18 10:17:49.907 GMT [22856] LOG:  database system is shut down
```

I learned it could be another process sending **SIGTERM**, **SIGINT** or **SIGQUIT** signals to database server. So i used **systemtap** to catch any signal for shutting down database server. After postgresql shut down again, i got this:

[image]

Now i have the PID of these processes which are sending shut down signals. What can i do to prevent this from happening again?

```
 VPS operating system is Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS. The backend is written in Django and database is Postgresql 12.
```

Comment: That kind of command: `COPY XXXFROM PROGRAM 'echo ... |base64 -d|bash'` is extremely suspicious (of being under attack) and the rest looks almost as bad.

Comment: Can you share the systemtap scriot you used to log the process?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have been hacked.  Rebuild the system, and this time pick a good password for your superuser, and don't let anyone log on from the outside at all unless that is necessary, and if it is don't let them do so as the superuser.

Comment: you mean shut down signals are being sent by an intruder? so main sever is hacked?

Comment: The PostgreSQL server, I don't know if you call that the "main" server.  `FROM PROGRAM` is a method to get from a PostgreSQL superuser login down to the OS level.  I don't know why they are killing their own entry point, maybe incompetence, maybe you have multiple hackers battling for control.

Comment: i'm keep getting this log after disallowing remote connection to postgres server: 2021-09-18 16:59:20.603 GMT [72035] postgres@postgres FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "120.79.186.121", user "postgres", database "postgres", SSL off

Comment: Right, so the attacker can no longer get in.  (And that is a known hacker IP address, see https://www.abuseipdb.com/check/120.79.186.121 )

Comment: So you think there is no need to rebuilding the system and the danger is eliminated?

Comment: @AminA2 You don't know what else they may have done - take the machine off-line; rebuild it (and this time w/ a sensible configuration).  Typically attackers will add other means of accessing the exploited box fairly early on.

Comment: @AminA2 whatever you do on that rebuild box make sure you go over the security advisories for Confluence: https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/confluence-security-advisory-2021-08-25-1077906215.html, specially the latest one as that one got scaled up after its first publication.